# Camel route just echoing the message from controller Redis GET and SET commands not working

Tags: apache-camel, spring-data-redis, spring-camel

I am trying to perform GET and SET operations in REDIS using camel route. Below is my camel context,
Not getting any error but route just echoing whatever input i am giving.

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:getDataFromRedis" />
        <log message="Received message: ${body}" />
        <setHeader name="CamelRedis.Key">
            <constant>${body}</constant>
        </setHeader>
                    <setHeader name="CamelRedis.Command">S
            <constant>GET</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <to
            uri="spring-redis://127.0.0.1:6379?connectionFactory=#jedisConnectionFactory&amp;redisTemplate=#redisTemplate" />
    </route>

    <route>
        <from uri="direct:setDataToRedis" />
        <log message="Received Key: ${body.id}" />
        <log message="Received Value: ${body.name}" />
        <setHeader name="CamelRedis.Key">
            <constant>${body.id}</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader name="CamelRedis.Value">S
            <constant>${body.name}</constant>
        </setHeader>
                    <setHeader name="CamelRedis.Command">S
            <constant>SET</constant>
        </setHeader>

        <to
            uri="spring-redis://127.0.0.1:6379?connectionFactory=#jedisConnectionFactory&amp;redisTemplate=#redisTemplate" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

But it is not working properly, just echoing message from controller,

@RestController
public class RedisCamelController {

```
@Autowired
CamelContext camelContext;

@Autowired
public RedisCamelController(CamelContext camelContext) {
    this.camelContext = camelContext;
}

@GetMapping(value="/getEmployeeDetails/{key}")
public String getValueFromRedis(@PathVariable String key) throws Exception {
    String messageBody = key;
    String result = camelContext.createProducerTemplate()
            .requestBody("direct:getDataFromRedis", messageBody, String.class);

    return result;
}

@PostMapping(value="/setEmployeeDetails/{key}/{value}")
public String getValueFromRedis(@PathVariable String key,@PathVariable String value) throws Exception {
    Employee emp=new Employee();
    emp.setId(key);
    emp.setName(value);
    String result = camelContext.createProducerTemplate()
            .requestBody("direct:setDataToRedis",emp, String.class);
    return result;
}
```

}

Could you please suggest what is incorrect here.

When the camel routes called it should Store and retrieve data from Redis server.
My expectation is to get Value if i send Command as GET and KEY in headers of route.

Example:

in Server:  >GET 10011

> "Aaa"

in REST endpoint : http://localhost:8080/getEmployeeDetails/10011
Response : Aaa

Comment: I'm a bit confused what your code is actually doing and what you'd expect it to do. The method of your POST handler is i.e. called `getValueFromRedis` when it actually writes data to Camel/Redis. You also store an `Employee` object as value for the provided key and yet you try to get a String from the GET counterpart.